# Wrong certificate in inter gear communication on Openshift

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openshift

I have two small gears on openshift with a custom domain name an my own SSL certificate.

When I access my gear from outside, they respond as expected with my own SSL certificate. But if I access own gear from the otherone, it still advertises with generic *.rhcloud.com certificate, when if I use my own domain name.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of how you are accessing the other gear internally from your application?

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift Online uses an Apache server in front of your gears for SSL termination and handling of custom domain names. When you setup a custom domain and SSL certificate on OpenShift Online the configuration was pushed to that Apache server, not to your individual gears.

Also, what sort of communication are you performing between your different gears? If you could provide some more concrete details on what you are trying to accomplish I could probably point you in the direction of how that is usually done on OpenShift.